# Pygame Button opens multiple applications

Tags: python, button, input, pygame, subprocess

I'm trying to write a script where it has a control panel and you can select what application u want to open only problem is that it opens that application multiple times please help only want to open it once.

I think the problem is that it checks if my mouse button is pressed multiple times a second and since my mouse is only being pressed for a second and it checks a couple times a second it does the if statement and completes it and opens the application multiple times.

```
# Importing Modules/Libraries.

import pygame
import subprocess

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

# Color Variables.

white_color = "#FFFFFF"

# Control Panel Variables.

ctrlpanel_run = True
ctrlpanel_program_select = True
ctrlpanel_program_select_input = True

# Main Arguments.

root = pygame.display.set_mode((700,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoDraw Control Panel")
root.fill("#333333")

# Draws Control panel Program Select Screen.

if ctrlpanel_program_select == True:

    title_font =  pygame.font.Font("./fonts/Exo-Bold.otf", 100)
    button_font = pygame.font.Font("./fonts/Exo-Bold.otf", 45)

    title_text = button_font.render("What Application?", True, white_color)
    root.blit(title_text, (165, 100))


    paint_button_rect = pygame.draw.rect(root, '#006EE6', pygame.Rect(70,200,200,90))
    paint3d_button_rect = pygame.draw.rect(root, '#006EE6', pygame.Rect(430,200,200,90))

    paint_button_text = button_font.render("Paint", True, white_color)
    root.blit(paint_button_text, (120, 225.5))

    paint3d_button_text = button_font.render("Paint 3D", True, white_color)
    root.blit(paint3d_button_text, (447, 225.5))

# Control panel Program Select Screen Input /// And Variables for Mouse positions and inputs.

mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_l, mouse_m, mouse_r = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
print(mouse_x, mouse_y)

while ctrlpanel_run:

    pygame.display.flip()

    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_l, mouse_m, mouse_r = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(mouse_x, mouse_y)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            ctrlpanel_run = False
            break

    if ctrlpanel_program_select_input == True:
        if mouse_x > 69 and mouse_x < 270:
            if mouse_y > 199 and mouse_y < 290:
                if mouse_l:
                    subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the problem already, as you state in your question. The solution is to stop checking for the mouse click as long as `mouse_l == True`. So something like this:

Initialize a `click_detected` boolean variable before your main loop. Then inside the loop:

```
if ctrlpanel_program_select_input == True:
    if mouse_x > 69 and mouse_x < 270:
        if mouse_y > 199 and mouse_y < 290:
            if mouse_l:
                click_detected = True
            if not mouse_l and click_detected:
                click_detected = False
                subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"])
```

This should open the application when you let go of the button, instead of when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the state of mouse buttons, you could use [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) generated by pressing or releasing the buttons.

You've already defined Rects for your buttons, so you can use [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to see if the mouse was clicked in the button.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        ctrlpanel_run = False
        break
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.button == 1:  # Left-click
            if paint_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", r"C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"])
            elif paint3d_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
                # launch Paint 3D
```